# My first project using C# & WPF - how to set a variable from .xaml.cs to appear in the textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to build a calculator with C# and WPF.

The purpose is to learn and test new things.

Here's the code:

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="calculator.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:calculator"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="400">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="295,224,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" FontFamily="Arial" Click="Button_Click9"/>
        <Button Content="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="166,224,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" FontFamily="Arial" Click="Button_Click8"/>
        <Button Content="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,224,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" FontFamily="Arial" Click="Button_Click7"/>
        <Button Content="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="295,254,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" FontFamily="Arial" Click="Button_Click6"/>
        <Button Content="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="166,254,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" FontFamily="Arial" Click="Button_Click5"/>
        <Button Content="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,254,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" FontFamily="Arial" Click="Button_Click4"/>
        <Button Content="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="295,285,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" FontFamily="Arial" Click="Button_Click3"/>
        <Button Content="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="166,285,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" FontFamily="Arial" Click="Button_Click2"/>
        <Button Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,285,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" FontFamily="Arial" Click="Button_Click1"/>
        <Button Content="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,316,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="321" FontFamily="Arial" Click="Button_Click0"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Margin="37,49,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="321" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="20" TextAlignment="Right"/>
        <Button Content="Calculate!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="154,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="+" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68" Height="57" Click="Button_Click_Add"/>
        <Button Content="/" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="290,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68" Height="57" Click="Button_Click_Multiply"/>
        <Button Content="*" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="206,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="69" Height="57" Click="Button_Click_Divide"/>
        <Button Content="-" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="122,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68" Height="57" Click="Button_Click_Subtract"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

XAML.CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace calculator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        List<int> lista = new List<int>();
        string number = "";
        int res = 0;

        private void Button_Click_Add(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int numberCreated;
            try
            {
                numberCreated = Int32.Parse(number);
                lista.Add(numberCreated);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Number could not be added!");
            }
            number = "";
            if(lista.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach(var element in lista)
                {
                    res += element;
                }
                lista.Clear();
            }
            MessageBox.Show(res.ToString());
        }

        private void Button_Click_Subtract(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int numberCreated = Int32.Parse(number);
                lista.Add(numberCreated);
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Number could not be added!");
            }
            number = "";
            if (lista.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (var element in lista)
                {
                    res -= element;
                }
                lista.Clear();
            }
            MessageBox.Show(res.ToString());
        }

        private void Button_Click_Multiply(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int numberCreated = Int32.Parse(number);
                lista.Add(numberCreated);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Number could not be added!");
            }
            number = "";
            if (lista.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (var element in lista)
                {
                    res *= element;
                }
                lista.Clear();
            }
            MessageBox.Show(res.ToString());
        }

        private void Button_Click_Divide(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int numberCreated = Int32.Parse(number);
                lista.Add(numberCreated);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Number could not be added");
            }
            number = "";
            if (lista.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (var element in lista)
                {
                    res /= element;
                }
                lista.Clear();
            }
            MessageBox.Show(res.ToString());
        }

        private void Button_Click9(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            number += "9";
        }

        private void Button_Click8(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            number += "8";
        }

        private void Button_Click7(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            number += "7";
        }

        private void Button_Click6(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            number += "6";
        }

        private void Button_Click5(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            number += "5";
        }

        private void Button_Click4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            number += "4";
        }

        private void Button_Click3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            number += "3";
        }

        private void Button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            number += "2";
        }

        private void Button_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            number += "1";
        }

        private void Button_Click0(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            number += "0";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm open to any tips and ideas you might give to an absolute beginner.

The reason I'm posting this is because I don't know how to make the "res" variable appear in the TextBox after each operation.

I saw online many people talking about TextBox.text, but I don't know how to use it.

Probably I have to use it in .xaml.cs, but how can I define TextBox? How will my program know which TextBox I want the text to be applied to?

Also, I feel like there's a better approach to create a number using the buttons rather than creating 10 separate functions (from button_click0 to button_click9) and I'd like to hear some ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello! Can you please strip out any unnecessary part of your sample code? That would make everyone's job easier:) Just leave the absolute minimum to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @CorentinPane I preffered to show anything because as I said, I'm a complete beginner, and I thought I might get some tips too :) thanks for your time

Comment: regarding your last paragraph, use an "ItemsControl"

Comment: you can use a single function for click event handler, then you can cast the sender object as button then check the content to know which button was clicked
var button = sender as Button, button.Content.ToString() will be 1,2,3,4 etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, e.g. Data Binding.
But I guess for learning, since this is your very first step in WPF, you should start more easy.

To access a control via code, you have to give it a name in XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TxtResult" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Margin="37,49,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="321" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="20" TextAlignment="Right"/>
```

By that, you can access your Textbox in Code:

```
private void Button_Click9(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    number += "9";
    this.TxtResult.Text = number;
}
```

EDIT to answer your last question:
Also for this there are many ways how to make it better or easier. If you want, you can do some research about Commands, Command Parameters and Command Bindings.
But for this simple Demo case, you can simply use the same event handler for all number buttons:

```
private void ButtonNumberClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    number += ((Button) sender).Content;
    this.TxtResult.Text = number;
}
```

The `sender` parameter contains the UI object that triggered the event handler, so you'll get a reference to the button that was clicked. And since the `Content` property of each button already contains the number you want to add to your string, you can grab it from there and append it to the `number` string.

Now in XAML you just have to assign that event handler to all ten buttons:

```
    <Button Content="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="295,224,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" FontFamily="Arial" Click="ButtonNumberClick"/>
    <Button Content="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="166,224,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" FontFamily="Arial" Click="ButtonNumberClick"/>
    <Button Content="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,224,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" FontFamily="Arial" Click="ButtonNumberClick"/>
    <Button Content="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="295,254,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" FontFamily="Arial" Click="ButtonNumberClick"/>
    <Button Content="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="166,254,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" FontFamily="Arial" Click="ButtonNumberClick"/>
    <Button Content="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,254,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" FontFamily="Arial" Click="ButtonNumberClick"/>
    <Button Content="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="295,285,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" FontFamily="Arial" Click="ButtonNumberClick"/>
    <Button Content="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="166,285,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" FontFamily="Arial" Click="ButtonNumberClick"/>
    <Button Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,285,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" FontFamily="Arial" Click="ButtonNumberClick"/>
    <Button Content="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,316,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="321" FontFamily="Arial" Click="ButtonNumberClick"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Also, can you respond to the last paragraph of my question please?

Comment: @JohnSmith Here we go :)